# Javascript Regexp split on unique character

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I would like to split a string only with the unique character '|' (and not '||').
Example:

the string:

```
hello || world | filter | other
```

would become:

```
['hello || world' , 'filter', 'other']
```

note: the pipes are not necessarily surrounded by whitespaces

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I would like to use 'pipes' in a unix fashion

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
'hello||world|filter|other'.match(/([^|].*?)[^|](?=(?:\||$)(?!\|))/g);
//=> ["hello||world", "filter", "other"]
```

**Explanation:** It starts matching a non pipe character from a non-pipe character that is not followed by another pipe (thus skipping double pipes).

OR to make it more accurate (and complex):

```
'ab|hello||world|filter|other'.match(/((^|[^|]).*?)[^|](?=(?:\||$)(?!\|))/g);
//=> ["ab", "hello||world", "filter", "other"]
```

Comment: This is needlessly complex for the problem at hand, and without any explanation it's not a particularly useful (helpful) answer anyway.

Comment: Without lookbehind support things get difficult. I am adding some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Negate the previous and subsequent chars.

```
vvar words = "hello || world | filter | other";
words = words.replace(/([^\|]\|[^\|])/g, 'SOMEUNIQUETOKEN').split('SOMEUNIQUETOKEN');
```

Replace the single bar with some token, and then split on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this with a two step process, first replace all of the single pipe characters with a null byte (`'\x00'`) and then splitting on null bytes:

```
'hello||world|filter|other'.replace(/(\|)?\|/g, function($0, $1) {
    return $1 ? $0 : '\x00';
}).split('\x00');
```

I removed the spaces from the string to make it more obvious that this method does not rely on any assumptions about the other characters around the pipes.

This uses a technique for mimicking negative lookbehinds in JavaScript from the following blog post:
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Of course the `'\x00'` can be replaced by any string, it just needs to be something that you can guarantee won't appear in any normal input (which is generally the case for null bytes unless you are dealing with binary data).